# Custom TitleBar in Qml

Tags: qt, qml

i want to create metro style titlebar (some thing like "mahapps.metro") for qml application with sticky edges and custom buttons and backgrounds , i already created some thing like this :

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.12
ApplicationWindow{
    id: window
    width: Screen.width * 5/6
    height: Screen.height * 5/6
    flags:Qt.Window | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
    menuBar : Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: 35
        color: Universal.color(Universal.Emerald)
        Row{
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            spacing: 5
            layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
            CustomButton{
                //close
            }
            CustomButton{
                //maximize
            }
            CustomButton{
                //minimize
            }
        }
        MouseArea{
            //deal with dragging
            anchors.fill: parent
            property variant clickPos: "1,1"
            onPressed: {
                if(window.visibility != 4 && window.visibility != 5)
                    clickPos  = Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)
            }
            onDoubleClicked: {
                var item = window.Maximized;
                if(window.visibility != 4 && window.visibility != 5){
                    window.showMaximized()
                }
                else{
                    window.showNormal()
                }
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                if(window.visibility != 4 && window.visibility != 5){
                    var delta = Qt.point(mouse.x-clickPos.x, mouse.y-clickPos.y)
                    window.x += delta.x;
                    window.y += delta.y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i have some questions :

1. how can i implement sticky edges in QML or QT ?
2. is there any library out there which already did this?
3. can i make a custom title bar meets my requirements with QTitleBar?
4. is there any open source application out there with custom title bar?
5. do material design has any style for windows , at least helps me in making it?

Answer (score -2):

you got 2 options to tackle this:

1. to create 4 different MouseArea for each edge (kind a cheese approach)
2. Other is to override window events and do it from scratch, which will give you full control over your window.